# Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I have a Pi 4B (4GB) on which I want to install Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop.

The Raspberry Pi Imager gives me the opportunity to only install Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop or 20.04 Server.
Older versions of the Imager also don't have the option to install 20.04 Desktop.

On the Ubuntu website they don't offer a downloadable .img of 20.04 Desktop, so I can't load my own image file to install via the Imager.

When trying to create a bootable SD card with Rufus, I can choose the 20.04 Desktop arm64 .iso fond [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/). The imaging process only takes about a minute before telling me it's finished, which feels way to fast. When trying to boot the Pi from that SD card it can't find anything on there and tries to find another source, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When trying to create a bootable SD card with Rufus...

Unfortunately just using `arm64` isn't sufficient; the Pi SD card has a sort of unique structure and (more significantly) requires some Pi specific stuff which will not be in a generic ARM image.

> The Raspberry Pi Imager gives me the opportunity to only install Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop or 20.04 Server.

I would guess the imager gives you all the options that are actually available, keeping in mind the last paragraph (unless you can find a **Pi ready** img in the flavour you want).

Anyway: As with most or all linux distros, Ubuntu Server is not really a distinct operating system from Ubuntu Desktop.  They are just two different configurations of the same thing.  So you can install the Server variant and then install a GUI desktop in it.